# How to have frontend, on s3, and backend on another server with the same domain

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3

I have the frontend part of an application on Amazon S3 and the backend on cloud66, with NGinx. The DNS have 'www.website.com' pointing on S3 and 'api.website.com' pointing on nginx. I want to use the same domain for both so 'www.website.com' still serve the frontend and 'www.website.com/api' have to serve backend.

I tried to add a redirection rule on S3 but it do a redirection with an extra request.

What can I do?

Comment: You'd have to put something like Cloudfront in front of it. That said, why? What's wrong with the current `api.website.com` approach for the backend? That's very common, easier, etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz It's because of CORS's preflight requests. I want to avoid it. I use cloudfront.

Comment: What's wrong with CORS preflight requests? That said, Cloudfront fully supports this. Add a second origin to the distribution and use a path match on `api/*`.

Comment: @ceejayoz  preflight requests adds an extra request and it's a little bit slower. I will check for cloudfront.

Comment: @ceejayoz I created this other question : https://serverfault.com/questions/803719/redirect-a-path-to-an-origin . I'm not very confortable with amazon services.